# RxJS typing error missing Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, rxjs

I'm adding Angular2 to an existing application and I'm getting exceptions with the webpack build regarding RxJS types.  I'm running webpack from a command line.  Here is a link to the repository.  From the Phase9 folder run 'npm install' and then 'npm start' to reproduce the error: https://github.com/ryanlangton/angular-upgrade/tree/master/Phase9

```
ERROR in [default] c:\Dev\angular-upgrade\Phase9\node_modules\rxjs\add\operator\zipAll.d.ts:2:15
Invalid module name in augmentation, module '../../Observable' cannot be found.
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "pretty": true,
        "stripInternal": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "public",
        "typings/browser",
        "typings/browser.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "angular-upgrade",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --colors --watch --display-error-details --display-cached --content-base src/",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/ryanlangton/angular-upgrade.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "ng-upgrade"
  ],
  "author": "Ryan Langton",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/ryanlangton/angular-upgrade/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/ryanlangton/angular-upgrade#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",

    "angular": "1.5.8",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.3.1",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "jquery": "3.1.0",
    "ng-metadata": "2.1.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "2.1.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "3.0.1",
    "css-loader": "0.23.1",
    "file":"0.2.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.22.0",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "open-browser-webpack-plugin": "0.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.12.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "source-map-loader": "0.1.5",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.4",
    "tslint": "3.14.0",
    "tslint-loader": "2.1.5",
    "typescript": "1.8.10",
    "typings": "1.3.2",
    "webpack": "1.13.1",
    "webpack-merge": "0.14.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.14.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

webpack.common.js

```
/**
 * @author: @AngularClass
 */

const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

/*
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
// problem with copy-webpack-plugin
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ForkCheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').ForkCheckerPlugin;
// const HtmlElementsPlugin = require('./html-elements-plugin');

/*
 * Webpack Constants
 */
const METADATA = {
  title: 'Angular 2 Upgrade',
  baseUrl: '/',
  isDevServer: helpers.isWebpackDevServer()
};

/*
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
 */
module.exports = {

  /*
   * Static metadata for index.html
   *
   * See: (custom attribute)
   */
  metadata: METADATA,

  /*
   * Cache generated modules and chunks to improve performance for multiple incremental builds.
   * This is enabled by default in watch mode.
   * You can pass false to disable it.
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cache
   */
   //cache: false,

  /*
   * The entry point for the bundle
   * Our Angular.js app
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
   */
  entry: {

    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor':    './src/vendor.ts',
    'main':      './src/main.ts'

  },

  /*
   * Options affecting the resolving of modules.
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
   */
  resolve: {

    /*
     * An array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions
     */
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json'],

    // Make sure root is src
    root: helpers.root('src'),

    // remove other default values
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],

  },

  /*
   * Options affecting the normal modules.
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module
   */
  module: {

    /*
     * An array of applied pre and post loaders.
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-preloaders-module-postloaders
     */
    preLoaders: [

      /*
       * Tslint loader support for *.ts files
       * See: https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader
       */
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'tslint-loader',
        exclude: [ /node_modules/ ]
      },

      /*
       * Source map loader support for *.js files
       * Extracts SourceMaps for source files that as added as sourceMappingURL comment.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/source-map-loader
       */
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader',
        exclude: [
          // these packages have problems with their sourcemaps
          helpers.root('node_modules/ng-metadata'),
          helpers.root('node_modules/rxjs'),
          helpers.root('node_modules/@angular'),
        //   helpers.root('node_modules/@ngrx'),
        //   helpers.root('node_modules/@angular2-material'),
        ]
      }

    ],

    /*
     * An array of automatically applied loaders.
     *
     * IMPORTANT: The loaders here are resolved relative to the resource which they are applied to.
     * This means they are not resolved relative to the configuration file.
     *
     * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders
     */
    loaders: [

      /*
       * Typescript loader support for .ts and Angular 2 async routes via .async.ts
       * Replace templateUrl and stylesUrl with require()
       * 
       * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader
       * See: https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-template-loader
       */
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader'],
        // loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
        exclude: [ /node_modules/ ]
      },

      /*
       * Json loader support for *.json files.
       *
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/json-loader
       */
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },

      /*
       * to string and css loader support for *.css files
       * Returns file content as string
       *
       */
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css' },
      // {
      //   test: /\.css$/,
      //   loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
      // },

      /* Raw loader support for *.html
       * Returns file content as string
       *
       * See: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
       */
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'raw-loader',
        exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
      },

      /* File loader for supporting images, for example, in CSS files.
      */
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file'
      }
    ]

  },

  /*
   * Add additional plugins to the compiler.
   *
   * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
   */
  plugins: [

    /*
     * Plugin: ForkCheckerPlugin
     * Description: Do type checking in a separate process, so webpack don't need to wait.
     *
     * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader#forkchecker-boolean-defaultfalse
     */
    new ForkCheckerPlugin(),

    /*
     * Plugin: OccurenceOrderPlugin
     * Description: Varies the distribution of the ids to get the smallest id length
     * for often used ids.
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#occurrenceorderplugin
     * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#minimize
     */
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true),

    /*
     * Plugin: CommonsChunkPlugin
     * Description: Shares common code between the pages.
     * It identifies common modules and put them into a commons chunk.
     *
     * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
     * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#multi-page-app
     */
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    /*
     * Plugin: CopyWebpackPlugin
     * Description: Copy files and directories in webpack.
     *
     * Copies project static assets.
     *
     * See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin
     */
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: 'src/assets',
      to: 'assets'
    }]),

    /*
     * Plugin: HtmlWebpackPlugin
     * Description: Simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles.
     * This is especially useful for webpack bundles that include a hash in the filename
     * which changes every compilation.
     *
     * See: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
     */
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),

    /*
     * Plugin: HtmlHeadConfigPlugin
     * Description: Generate html tags based on javascript maps.
     *
     * If a publicPath is set in the webpack output configuration, it will be automatically added to
     * href attributes, you can disable that by adding a "=href": false property.
     * You can also enable it to other attribute by settings "=attName": true.
     *
     * The configuration supplied is map between a location (key) and an element definition object (value)
     * The location (key) is then exported to the template under then htmlElements property in webpack configuration.
     *
     * Example:
     *  Adding this plugin configuration
     *  new HtmlElementsPlugin({
     *    headTags: { ... }
     *  })
     *
     *  Means we can use it in the template like this:
     *  <%= webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags %>
     *
     * Dependencies: HtmlWebpackPlugin
     */
    // new HtmlElementsPlugin({ 
    //   headTags: require('./head-config.common')
    // }),

  ],

  /*
   * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
   * Description: Node configuration
   *
   * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
   */
  node: {
    global: 'window',
    crypto: 'empty',
    process: true,
    module: false,
    clearImmediate: false,
    setImmediate: false
  }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awesome-typescript-loader 2+ supports only Typescript 2+ and webpack 2.
https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/179

The solution was to change my package.json to use v1.1.1

Previous:

```
 "awesome-typescript-loader": "2.1.1",
```

Fixed:

```
 "awesome-typescript-loader": "1.1.1",
```